# Communicate with process' stdin and stdout in asyncio.subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, python-asyncio

I have written test code for subprocess, which kinda do some tasks one by one:

```
import sys
import json
import time
while True:
    data=json.loads(input())
    time.sleep(2)
    print(json.dumps({'status': 'ok', 'data': data}))
```

I launch this subprocess from jupyterlab(for debuging purposes) using asyncio.subprocess. Here is the code for launch:

```
subproc=await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec('python',  'test_io.py', 
        stdin=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,  stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE)
```

Here is the code to send the data to subprocess:

```
subproc.stdin.writelines([json.dumps('test').encode()])
#subproc.stdin.write_eof()
await subproc.stdin.drain()
```

Here is the code to receive output. It hangs:

```
await subproc.stdout.read()
```

If I uncoment subproc.stdin.write_eof() in sending code, reveiving code not hangs but I find an error in stderr:

```
await subproc.stderr.read()

b'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "test_io.py", line 5, in <module>\n    data=json.loads(input())\nEOFError: EOF when reading a line\n'
```

I have made several attempts to solve the problem and recognize that I have to sent something like '\r\n'(I tried both '\n' and '\r\n' and '\n\n'- them all not work) to allow input to read the line but not EOF since it close input at all.

Comment: Why mix asyncio and subprocesses?

Comment: Because you revceive syncrone code if you are not mixing. And you also loose most of benefits of performing some part of your code in separate subprocess

Comment: It not asynchronous I/O if you need to communicate with it.

Comment: If you want to continuously exchange data between Python processes, a multiprocessing.Queue or external queue (redis/rabbit) are better options than stdin/stdout which are file objects.